# IntelliJ shows "Cannot resolve configuration property" error for Spring Cloud GCP PubSub configuration

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-cloud-gcp

My Spring Boot application depends on Spring Cloud GCP PubSub, with maven dependency specified as below:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I configured for it in application.yaml based on its doc at https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/spring-cloud-gcp/3.4.0/reference/html/index.html#cloud-pubsub, my IntelliJ shows "the configuration property is not found", see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coryI.png)

Below is a snippet of my applcation.yaml file:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: cat-service
  cloud:
    gcp:
      pubsub:
        subscriber:
          min-duration-per-ack-extension: 300 # 5 minutes
    kubernetes:
      loadbalancer:
        mode: service
      reload:
        enabled: true
        mode: polling
        period: 5000
      config:
        sources:
        - name: ${spring.application.name}
    loadbalancer:
      ribbon:
        enabled: false
```

My questions are:

1. How do I tell whether it's a real configuration error (e.g. the dependency does not support this config property), or is it something wrong with IntelliJ?
2. How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: Please share a [minimal reproducible project sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to check whether it is a problem with the IDE or a project misconfiguration

Comment: @EgorKlepikov I have added a snippet of my application.yaml with that field, please let me know if it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add project-id, subscription-name and credentials to your application.yaml?

Comment: My application is deployed on GKE, so it's just using the default project-id and credential. The subscription-name is hardcoded in the application itself.

Do they have to be in application.yaml?